# Javascript - Prototyped Function Name Returned As A Key Of Associative Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype-programming

I'm wanting to add a prototyped function to javascript's array object.

The problem I'm having is that when I step the keys of an array, the prototyped function's name appears in the array's keys.

Here's a sample to illustrate the problem:

> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>       Array.prototype.foo = function () {
>         // do something
>       }
>       function keys() {
>         var fruit = ["apples","pears","bannanas"];
>         for (key in fruit) alert(key); // alerts: 0, 1, 2, foo
>       }
>     </script>
>   </head>
>   <body onload="keys();">
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Any ideas on how I can get around this?

I don't *have* to prototype the function but, from a readability point of view, I'd prefer to.

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, the real world implementation of the above example iterates through an associative array, hence the for..in loop

**EDIT:** Thanks for the replies guys but I think you're missing what I'm after. What I'm wanting to know is whether I can add a prototyped function to javascript's array object (or declare the function in a different way that would have the same effect) without having the function name pitch up while iterating through an array via a for..in loop. Take the `indexOf` function for example. Javascript seems to define it internally in such a way that it doesn't appear in the keys of the object/array (right?). Can this same behaviour be reproduced at runtime?

Comment: Don't use a `for...in` to iterate over an array. Use a normal `for` loop and then you won't have this problem.

Comment: Yeah unless it's an associative array - I don't know of a way of iterating through an associative array without using a for..in loop..

Comment: or you can do it but check the type is not a function 
if (fruit[key].constructor != Function)

Comment: You should update your example to show that.

Comment: yeah, I thought of that too but, as things sit, that would mean changing a lot of code in my project. I'm using associative arrays in quite a few places and the prototyped function is mucking things up :)

Comment: There are no "associative arrays" in javascript. There are Objects and Arrays. Arrays are just Objects with a special length property and some handy methods. Objects are just unordered bundles of name/value pairs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I appreciate it isn't always available but you can avoid the whole mess by using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or if you're using a JavaScript library (quite likely and highly recommended) then you have something like Prototype's [`Enumerable#each()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/each/), Sugar's [`Array#each()`](http://sugarjs.com/api/Array/each) or jQuery's [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether `fruit.hasOwnProperty(key)` in the loop.

Comment: Thanks, that will come in handy

Answer (score 0):

To avoid inherited enumerable properties with for..in, use a hasOwnProperty test:

```
for (var p in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    // p is a property of obj and not inherited
  }
}
```

Using for..in with arrays is not recommended - if you want an object, use an Object.

Arrays are normally used where the members are accessed in order, e.g. using a counter in a loop. Using for..in the order in which properties are returned is implementation dependant and differs between browsers, so you can't guarantee order.

Answer (score 0):

As James says use rather than...

```
function keys() {
  var fruit = ["apples", "pairs", "bananas"];
  for(var key in fruit) {
    alert(key);
  }
}
```

Instead do the following...

```
function keys() {
  var fruit = ["apples", "pairs", "bananas"];
  for(var i = 0; i < fruit.length; ++i) {
    alert(i);
  }
}
```

As the length property will only update with the indexed array items and not items added to the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate trough an associative array with for in and get what you want i would use `typeof` to type-check the propriety and restrict to non-functions. You can use
    `number`,
    `string`,
    `boolean`,
    `object`,
    function
    and `undefined` 
with typeof
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/259s7zc1%28v=vs.94%29.aspx